# Emit a function to get the value of :checked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to emit a function on a input field with :checked to the parent component to get back what the value of the :checked should be? Currently trying to do it like this.

Simple function that returns false

```
isAllStudentsFromClassSelected(){
    return false
},
```

Input field in child component that is trying to get the :checked value by emiting a function to a parent component

```
<input class="form-check-input class-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="all-tutors" :checked="$emit('testing2')">
```

The emitter calling the function

```
@testing2="isAllStudentsFromClassSelected"
```

With this code I seem to get back a checked checkbox every single time even though the function should return false.

Comment: `:checked` should be `@checked`. But I'm not sure if  `checked` is an event. If checked does not work you can use `@change` and then in your method check the value.

Comment: @S.Visser I don't want a function to run on change I am trying to use a function return true or false depending on what is in the state.

Answer (score 0):

use computed:

parent:

```
<my-component :isChecked="isAllStudentsFromClassSelected"></my-component>

computed: {
  isAllStudentsFromClassSelected(){
    return false
  }
}
```

child:

```
<input class="form-check-input class-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="all-tutors" :checked="isChecked">

props: ['isChecked']
```